# Customize Request Timeout Message in IBM Worklight v6.0

Tags: worklight-studio, worklight-server, worklight-security, worklight-runtime

When the request to the worklight server from the Mobile device times-out, I get the following Error and it looks like it is being pushed from the Worklight framework

```
http://serveraddress:portno/console/apps/services/api/app_title...
Make sure the host address is available to the app (especially relevant for android and iphone apps
```

Now It's not ideal to reveal the server address to the end user. And I'm not able to figure out as to where this can be customized. Need suggestion on how to modify this error Message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFSIK Try Change the log level from your `wlInitOptions` to `error` and check the logs to disable the timeout error messages

```
`var wlInitOptions = {

    connectOnStartup : true,
    timeout : 60000,
    logger : {enabled: true, level: 'error', stringify: true, pretty: false,
    tag: {level: false, pkg: true}, whitelist: [], blacklist: []},
    analytics : {
        enabled: false
    }

};`
```

Comment: You mean to say this will disable the Worklight Error Message

Comment: it wil disable the log messages for your worklight server calls and responses. In your case it is timeout error message from server

Comment: But Can I have my own "Customized Message" in this scenario ?

Comment: Try the following code in your failure function of invokeprocedure for the customized error message in timout.
`onFailureOfSomeAdapterProcedureCall:function(obj){

 if(obj.errorCode == "REQUEST_TIMEOUT"){
  // Timeout happens
 }else if (obj.errorCode == "PROCEDURE_ERROR") {
  //procedure is giving some error
 };
}`